# Solving T(n)=4T(n/2)+n with iterative methode

Tags: algorithm, iteration, complexity-theory

I am trying to solve a recurrence using iterative method. I know the solution should be θ(n^2) but I'm not able to solve it with the iterative method.

This is how far I got:

1. T(n) = 4T(n/2)+n
2. T(n) = 4(4T(n/4)+n/2)+n
3. T(n) = 4(4(4T(n/8)+n/4)+n/2)+n

[image: 4^{i}*T(\frac{n}{2^{i}})+ \sum ?]

I dont know how to calculate the sum. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define `k` such that `2^k = n` (`^` stands for raising into power). So we have

```
T(n) = 4 * T(n / 2) + n
```

as

```
T(2^k) = 2^2 * T(2^(k-1)) + 2^k
```

Let's *unwind* it:

```
T(2^k) = 2^2 * T(2^(k-1)) + 2^k =
       = 2^4 * T(2^(k - 2)) + 2^(k + 1) + 2^k =
       = 2^6 * T(2^(k - 3)) + 2^(k + 2) + 2^(k + 1) + 2^k =
       = 2^8 * T(2^(k - 4)) + 2^(k + 3) + 2^(k + 2) + 2^(k + 1) + 2^k = 
         ...
       = T(0) * (2^(2 * k) + ... + 2^(k + 2) + 2^(k + 1) + 2^k) =
       = T(0) * (2^k * (2^k + 2^(k - 1) + ... + 4 + 2 + 1)) = 
       = T(0) * (2^k * (2 * 2^k - 1))
```

Time to return back from `k` to `n`; since we have `2^k = n`:

```
T(n) = T(0) * n * (2 * n - 1)
```

Having close formula for `T(n)` we can easily compute `θ`:

```
    θ(T(0) * n * (2 * n - 1)) = 
  = T(0) * θ(n * (2 * n - 1)) =
  = 2 * T(0) * θ(n^2) =
  = θ(n^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate it easily by same way you have done:

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2)+n                  
T(n) = 4(4T(n/4)+n/2)+n         =  4^2 T(n/4)     + 2n + n
T(n) = 4(4(4T(n/8)+n/4)+n/2)+n  =  4^3 T(n/8)     + 4n + 2n + n
                                  |--first part--|--second part--|
```

At first, since the iteration halves each time, then this iteration happens `log(n)` turns at max.

Now for the first part, after `i`th turn is `4^i`, so it will be from `O(4^log(n)) = O(n^2)`.

For the second part, it is a geometric serie `n+2n+4n+8n....+n*2^i=n*(2^(i+1)-1)`. So its amortized time for `log(n)` turn will be `O(n*2^log(n))=O(n^2)`.

Since both part is `O(n^2)` and they are summed up, the amortized time of total is also `O(n^2)`.